# How can I extract a string out of an object that contains this string?

Tags: c#, string, object

I created a Yaml that looks like this:

```
Directories:
    - ./Libraries:
        - DLLList.yml

    - ./Output:
        - None
```

Now I deserialized that yaml into a list of Objects:

```
List<object> allDirectoriesList = new List<object>();
List<string> allFileNames = new List<string>();

using (var reader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText("./FileConfig.yml")))
{
    allDirectoriesList = deserializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(reader)["Directories"] as List<Object>;
}

foreach (var directory in allDirectoriesList)
{
    var directoryAsDictionary = (Dictionary<object, object>)directory;
    List<object> list = directoryAsDictionary.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();

    IEnumerable<string> _fileList = list.Select(i => i.ToString());

    List<string> fileList = _fileList.ToList<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count(); i++)
    {
        var x = (string)list[i];
    }
}
```

`directory` is an object of type Dictionary where I converted it into a List in this part:

```
var directoryAsDictionary = (Dictionary<object, object>)directory;
List<object> list = directoryAsDictionary.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```

This `list` contains 1 object of type string, where the filename is stored. But I can't get these strings out of the objects. If I cast them, or convert them ToString(), I always get `` "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]" ``, but it has to be `"DLLList.yml"` in this case

Comment: @jdweng YAML is not binary Data. It is just another text format. like JSON

Comment: As I read your code I think you are constructing a List of objects that really are Dictionaries of objects with keys of type object. This will involve much casting to get to the string within the dictionary.Why is the data structure you constructing so complicated? Why do you need object types when you know that you're storing dictionaries? Do you really need to create dictionaries with unknown types and unknown key types??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `YamlDotNet`:

```
        List<object> allDirectoriesList = new List<object>();

        using (var reader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText("./FileConfig.yml")))
        {
            allDirectoriesList = new DeserializerBuilder().Build().Deserialize<dynamic>(reader)["Directories"] as List<object>;
        }

        foreach (var directory in allDirectoriesList)
        {
            var directoryAsDictionary = (Dictionary<object, object>)directory;
            List<object> list = directoryAsDictionary.SelectMany(kvp => (List<object>)kvp.Value).ToList();

            List<string> _fileList = list.Select(Convert.ToString).ToList();

            foreach(var file in _fileList)
                Console.WriteLine($"Item: {file} found in {Convert.ToString(directoryAsDictionary.Keys.First())}");
        }
```

Basically you were trying to turn the dictionary value to a string, but it was a List. By using `SelectMany`, it can flatten all the lists into one and use that. There were a few redundant casts, which I've also removed. For future reference, try to make your structures as simple as possible and deserialise them into structs/classes - you'll find this a lot easier that way.